# How to submit a form with session in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the [website](https://www.partslink24.com/) using **Scrapy**. To get the content which I want I need to login first. The url is [login_url](https://www.partslink24.com/partslink24/user/login.do)

There I have form as follows:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
LOGIN_URL1 = "https://www.partslink24.com/partslink24/user/login.do"
class PartsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "parts"
    login_url = LOGIN_URL1
    start_urls = [
        login_url,
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        form_data = {
            'accountLogin': COMPANY_ID,
            'userLogin': USERNAME,
            'loginBean.password': PASSWORD
        }
        yield FormRequest(url=self.login_url, formdata=form_data, callback=self.parse1)

    def parse1(self, response):
        inspect_response(response, self)
        print("RESPONSE: {}".format(response))


def start_scraper(vin_number):
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(PartsSpider)
    process.start()
```

But the problem is that they check if the session is activated and I get an error, the form can not be submitted.

When I check the response which I get after submitting the login form, I get the following error:

[image]

The code on their site which checks that is as follows:

```
var JSSessionChecker = {
    check: function()
    {
        if (!Ajax.getTransport())
        {
            alert('NO_AJAX_IN_BROWSER');
        }
        else
        {
            
            new Ajax.Request('/partslink24/checkSessionCookies.do', {
                method:'post',
                onSuccess: function(transport)
                {
                    if (transport.responseText != 'true')
                    {
                        if (Object.isFunction(JSSessionChecker.showError)) JSSessionChecker.showError(); 
                    }
                },
                onFailure: function(e) 
                { 
                    if (Object.isFunction(JSSessionChecker.showError)) JSSessionChecker.showError(); 
                },
                onException: function (request, e) 
                { 
                    if (Object.isFunction(JSSessionChecker.showError)) JSSessionChecker.showError(); 
                }
            });
        }
    },
    
    showError: function()
    {
        var errorElement = $('sessionCheckError');
        if (errorElement)
        {
            errorElement.show();
        }
    }
};
JSSessionChecker.check();
```

And on success it returns only **true**.

Is there any way that I can activate the session before submitting a form?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The error page which I get using the answer from @fam.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried replacing `FormRequest(url=self.login_url,` with `FormRequest.from_response(response,`?

Comment: @tomjn Yes I am.

Comment: `scrapy` can't run `JavaScript` - it can be simpler to add extension which uses `Selenium` or `Splash` to control web browser which can run JavaScript. ie. [scapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium)

Comment: @furas Any idea how to do that in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this code.

```
import scrapy

LOGIN_URL1 = "https://www.partslink24.com/partslink24/user/login.do"
class PartsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "parts"
    login_url = LOGIN_URL1
    start_urls = [
        login_url,
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        form_data = {
            'loginBean.accountLogin': "COMPANY_ID",
            'loginBean.userLogin': "USERNAME",
            'loginBean.sessionSqueezeOut' : "false",
            'loginBean.password': "PASSWORD",
            'loginBean.userOffsetSec' : "18000",
            'loginBean.code2f' : ""
        }
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response=response, url=self.login_url, formdata=form_data, callback=self.parse1)

    def parse1(self, response):
        #scrapy.inspect_response(response, self)
        print("RESPONSE: {}".format(response))


def start_scraper(vin_number):
    process = scrapy.CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(PartsSpider)
    process.start()
```

I am not getting an error and the response is as follows:

```
RESPONSE: <200 https://www.partslink24.com/partslink24/user/login.do>
```

**EDIT:**
The following code is for Selenium. It will log you into the page easily. You only need to download the chrome driver and install Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.partslink24.com/partslink24/user/login.do")

# enter the form fields
company_ID = "company id"
user_name = "user name"
password = "password"

company_ID_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='accountLogin']")
company_ID_input.send_keys(company_ID)
time.sleep(1)

user_name_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='userLogin']")
user_name_input.send_keys(user_name)
time.sleep(1)

password_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='inputPassword']")
password_input.send_keys(password)
time.sleep(1)

# click the search button and get links from first page
click_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@tabindex='5']")
click_btn.click()
time.sleep(5)
```

Don't forget to change the credentials.

Comment: The response is 200, but the page is not the page which I should get after login. I've updated my question with the photo.

Comment: Thank you for providing additional information. How are you checking if you are getting an error or not as the response is 200? Also, I dont have the credentials to move further and check if I am actually able to login. Have you tried `formxpath = "//form"` instead of using `url=self.login_url`? Let me know!

Comment: With `inspect_response(response, self)` , after that ypu can do `view(response)` and you see the response in the browser. Can we go to the chat?

Comment: Ok, I got it. Sure, lets have a chat.

Comment: How can I start chart? :-)

Comment: I have added another solution using Selenium. Please have a look at it. I am sure it will solve your problem. Regarding the chat, I don't know myself :/ Let me know if the new solution works.